# Gathering reactions from a private DM but ignoring bot reactions

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I'm making a command for my bot where it sends you this message:[image]

The two reactions (tick and cross) become pre-reacted by the bot to show the user what to do. I wan't my bot to wait a set period of time and check for what the user has reacted with, at the moment my bot counts its own reactions so the count is false.

How would I go about doing this, everything I have tried has failed and I can no longer Ctrl+Z to the point where I have a vaguely working code.

Thanks.

EDIT: I actually fixed my problem about half an hour ago after many attempts, here's what I used:

```
res1 = await client.wait_for_reaction(emoji="✅", message=message_1, timeout=10)
res2 = await client.wait_for_reaction(emoji="❌", message=message_1, timeout=10)
if not res1.user == None or not res2.user == None:
   if not res1.user.id == client.user or res2.user.id == client.user:
```

Comment: _at the moment my bot counts its own reactions so the count is false._ can you show us your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to add a `check` to you `wait_for_reaction` that just checks the reacting user against `client.user`.  This has the benefit of also working in scenarios where you want to accept exactly one reaction, and can't do another loop if you accidentally see a bot reaction

```
def not_bot_reaction(reaction, user):
    return user != client.user

...

res1 = await client.wait_for_reaction(emoji="✅", message=message_1, timeout=10, check=not_bot_reaction)
res2 = await client.wait_for_reaction(emoji="❌", message=message_1, timeout=10, check=not_bot_reaction)

if res1 or res2:  # If the wait_for times out, it will return None instead of the namedtuple
    ...
```